# Vue 3 require is not defined for img src

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

When i use require in Vue 3, on vue 2 all works

```
<img :src="require('./img/1.png')" />
```

I get error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
      at <Creator key=1 > 
      at <Character> 
      at <App>

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
      at Proxy._sfc_render (creator.vue:14:24)
      at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:895:44)
      at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5059:57)
      at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
      at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5185:9)
      at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4968:9)
      at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4926:17)
      at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4518:21)
      at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4714:13)
      at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4623:17)
```

Just text text text text

Comment: I don't understand purpose of this. Why don't you use <img src="/img/1.png" />? Looks like require is some function you didn't define in "setup"

Comment: It's specific to your vite setup, not vue specifically.

Comment: I used a static path to simplify the issue, the bottom line is that I need a dynamic import. <img :src="'./img/' + selectedItem.img" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```js
<img :src="imageSrc" />
...
<script>
...
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    imageSrc() {
      return new URL(`./img/${selectedItem}.png`, import.meta.url).href;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Still, too bad of vite to have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is a webpack specific feature to handle assets import.

Using vite, it's done differently: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url

With the vue vite plugin (that you certainly are using), you can just use a relative or absolute path inside `:src=""` and vite will convert it to a dynamic import under the hood. So it's transparent for you.

```
<img src="./imgs/cat.jpeg" width="300px" height="50px">
<img src="~/assets/dog.jpg" width="300px" height="50px">
```

Comment: I need a dynamic import. <img :src="'./img/' + selectedItem.img" />

Answer (score 1):

i just switched to webpack for vue 3 and require worked again